# submitting always the same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

im working in a app that lists records, and each record i have a button to edit and delete.

In my for look i have wrapped up in the delete button a form that takes a action url path, what makes different from each other is that takes a different id to later identify the record in the deletion. With this im using sweet alert, that popups up before deleting record just to confirm, and in case that confirms it submits the form, the only issue is that submiting the first form, and i not that because the id is the first one, i believe that isnt submitting the current form in my javascript, cant figure out why isnt working.

My code JS:

```
 <script>
        $('button.delete').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                        title: "Are you sure",
                       text: "Can i delete?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Sim!",
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    },
                    function(){
                        $(".delete-form").submit();
                    });
        })
    </script>
```

inside for loop

```
 <form class="delete-form" style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/admin/categories/{{$category->id}}"  >
                                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete</button>

                                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".delete-form")` matches *all* the forms, not just the one with the button the user clicked on. You need to use DOM traversal from `$(this)` to get the selected form.

```
    $('button.delete').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest(".delete-form");
        swal({
                    title: "Are you sure",
                   text: "Can i delete?",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Sim!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(){
                    form.submit();
                });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` property to submit the specific form like this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var action_attr = $(this).closest('form.delete-form').attr('action');
   console.log("Delete form - " + action_attr);
    // $(this).closest('.delete-block').find('form').submit();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="delete-form" style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/admin/categories/1"  >
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete 1</button>
</form>


<form class="delete-form" style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/admin/categories/2"  >
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete 2</button>
</form>



<form class="delete-form" style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/admin/categories/3"  >
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete 3</button>
</form>
```

Hope thi helps!